# How can I display an image using Pillow?

Tags: python, tkinter, python-imaging-library

I want to display a gif image using Pillow

Here is my simple code:

```
from tkinter import *
from PIL import Image, ImageTk 
import tkinter as Tk 

image = Image.open("Puissance4.gif") 
image.show()
```

But nothing happens...

All help will be appreciated

Thanks!

Comment: What does `from PIL import ImageShow`; `ImageShow._viewers` return?

Comment: It returns `[]` Thanks!

Comment: What OS are you using?

Comment: I use Raspbian on a Raspberry Pi

Comment: What command do you use to display images from the command line?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

PIL provides a `show` method which attempts to detect your OS and choose an
appropriate viewer. On Unix it tries calling the imagemagick command `display`
or `xv`. On Macs it uses `open`, on Windows it uses... something else.

If it can't find an appropriate viewer, `ImageShow._viewers` will be an empty list.

On Raspbian, you'll need to install an image viewer such as `display`, `xv` or [`fim`](http://www.raspberrypi-spy.co.uk/2014/09/how-to-display-images-on-raspbian-command-line/). (Note a search on the web will show that there are many image viewers available.) Then 
you can tell PIL to use it by specifying the `command` parameter:

```
image.show(command='fim')
```

---

To display an image in Tkinter, you could use something like:

```
from PIL import Image, ImageTk 
import tkinter as tk 

root = tk.Tk()
img = Image.open("image.gif")
tkimage = ImageTk.PhotoImage(img)
tk.Label(root, image=tkimage).pack()
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: I can't get this to work with `command='fbi'` now that `fim` is depricated: http://www.raspberrypi-spy.co.uk/2014/09/how-to-display-images-on-raspbian-command-line/