# Pillow doesn't show image

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-imaging-library

Using Pillow 3.4.2 for python 3.5 i am attempting to display the image Lenna using this code:

```
from PIL import Image
filename = 'C:/Users/Thomas/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Lenna.png'
pic = Image.open(filename)
pic.show()
```

But I get the following error upon running the code:

> builtins.AttributeError: module 'PIL._imaging' has no attribute 'fill'

Comment: PIL uses an external viewer to display images. What does `from PIL import ImageShow; ImageShow._viewers` return? (thanks to [unutbu](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28139637/how-can-i-display-an-image-using-pillow#comment44650991_28139637) for that command)

Comment: @PM2Ring It returned `[<PIL.ImageShow.WindowsViewer object at 0x033E2950>]`

Comment: Weird. If I do `import PIL._imaging; dir(PIL._imaging)` in the interpreter `'fill'` is one of the attributes in the returned list. FWIW, I'm using Pillow 3.3.0 with Python 3.6 on Linux. I vaguely remember having problems installing Pillow when I upgraded to 3.6, so it _might_ be worthwhile trying Pillow 3.3.0.

Comment: Is this the *only* error that you get?

Comment: Did you install Pillow from a  wheel or did you compile it? It might be that the Pillow you've got doesn't really work on your Python...